# Google Maps initial Camera Postition is not being set

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-provider

I am trying to get the coordinates from an address string using geocoder and setting the initial camera position using LatLng of that address. But google map shows blue screen. On zooming out i found it was ocean. How can i set it to my desired location using the startPoint string?

```
String startPoint = '1 Ash Park, Pembroke Dock, SA72';


    @override
  void initState() {
    initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    locationVM = Provider.of<LocationViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    await locationVM.getCoordinates(startPoint, endPoint);
    locationVM.addMarker(
        LatLng(locationVM.coordinatesStart!.latitude!,
            locationVM.coordinatesStart!.longitude!),
        "origin",
        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker);
    locationVM.addMarker(
        LatLng(locationVM.coordinatesEnd!.latitude!,
            locationVM.coordinatesEnd!.longitude!),
        "destination",
        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90));
    await locationVM.getPolyLines();
  }
```

ViewModel getCoordinates funtion

```
Future<void> getCoordinates(String addressStart,String addressEnd) async {
    LocationService locationService = LocationService();
    coordinatesStart = (await locationService.getCoordinates(addressStart))!;
    coordinatesEnd = (await locationService.getCoordinates(addressEnd))!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

LocationService getCoordinates function

```
Future<Coordinates?> getCoordinates (String address) async {
    var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(address);
    var first = addresses.first;
    print("Adddress ${first.featureName} : Coordinates ${first.coordinates}");
    return first.coordinates;
  }


GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: (controller) {
                      setState(() {
                        mapController = controller;
                      });
                    },
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                        locationVM.coordinatesStart!.latitude!,
                        locationVM.coordinatesStart!.longitude!,
                      ),
                      zoom: 10,
                    ),
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(locationVM.markers.values),
                    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(locationVM.polylines.values),
                  ),
```

And the exceotion it is throwing in the console is below:

```
Unsupported class loader
E/flutter ( 8235): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(failed, Failed, null, null)
E/flutter ( 8235): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter ( 8235): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter ( 8235): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8235): #2      LocalGeocoding.findAddressesFromQuery (package:flutter_geocoder/services/local.dart:18:28)
E/flutter ( 8235): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8235): #3      LocationService.getCoordinates (package:goochil_driver_app/services/location_service.dart:9:21)
E/flutter ( 8235): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8235): #4      LocationViewModel.getCoordinates (package:goochil_driver_app/viewModels/location_view_model.dart:20:25)
E/flutter ( 8235): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8235): #5      _TripDetailsState.initialize (package:goochil_driver_app/views/trip_details.dart:41:5)
E/flutter ( 8235): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8235): 
W/goochil.taxiap( 8235): Unsupported class loader
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Most likely you're not getting the coordinates in your initialize()  method.
   Try to print out out the coordinates brought in the initialize method.
2. Am not very sure about this but in the initialize() method you're using provider with
   listen set to false. So logically thinking the **locationVM.coordinatesStart** won't
   have the updated values coz it's not listening to changes.
   A fix to this would be to place another provider variable in the widget build method.
   See below.....

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var locationProvider = Provider.of<LocationViewModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
     body: GoogleMap(
             onMapCreated: (controller) {
                  setState(() {
                    mapController = controller;
                  });
                  },
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(
                   locationProvider.coordinatesStart!.latitude!,
                   locationProvider.coordinatesStart!.longitude!,
                   ),
              zoom: 10,
                    ),
               markers: Set<Marker>.of(locationProvider.markers.values),
               polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(locationProvider.polylines.values),
         ),
   );
  }
```

Comment: i have done it .. idea was correct but with some changes. But still map is not loading to correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

So it was problem with view model initalization. I did the following changes

```
@override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<LocationViewModel>(context,listen: false).getData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and in build method i acces it like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var locationVM = Provider.of<LocationViewModel>(context);
```

and the ViewModel get data looks like this

```
Future<void> getData() async {
    await this.getCoordinates();
    this.addMarker(LatLng(coordinatesStart!.latitude!, coordinatesStart!.longitude!), 'origin', BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker);
    await this.getPolyLines();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

But the camera position is still not being initialized to correct coordinates.